# ReferenceError before initialization

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code below but don't understand why I am getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization

ref={simulateClick} onClick={(e)=> {
     let a = e.target.value
     (a === "R") ? (
        do_something
     ) : null
   }
}
```

Here is the code for `simulateClick`

```
const simulateClick = (e) => {
    e.click();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access `a` anywhere else?

Comment: @MattU - no, just as shown in the ternary operator alone within my code snippet.